# Помогите правильно составить POJO для запроса Retrofit XML

Tags: android, xml, retrofit

РАзбираюсь с запросами через Retrofit.
С простыми документами с большего все понятно и все получается.
Но вот в одном месте приходит ответ XML подобного вида:

```
<data>
<e/>
<from>
    <id>487</id>
    <sspd>2100055</sspd>
</from>
<to>
    <id>482</id>
    <code_exp>2100063</code_exp><gid>614</gid>
</to>
<routes>
    <item>
        <index>0</index>
        <is_main_from>0</is_main_from>
        <train_type>regional_economy</train_type>
       <places>
            <item>
                <free/>
                <price>0.7</price>
            </item>
        </places>
    </item><item>
        <index>1</index>
        <is_main_from>0</is_main_from>
        <train_type>regional_economy</train_type>
       <places>
            <item>
                <free/>
                <price>0.7</price>
            </item>
        </places>
    </item>
```

И я никак не могу понять как забрать нужные мне поля.
мне нужно выдернуть из списка полей `</item>` только определенные позиции, например `<train_type>`

Я делаю вот так , но почему то получаю ошибку)(

```
@Root(name = "data" ,strict=false)
```

public class Responce {

```
@ElementList(inline = true)
public List<Item> itemList;



@Root(name = "item",strict=false)
class Item {
    @Element(name = "train_type")
    String name;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Вы привели полную структуру xml или только кусок?

Comment: Нет не полную, вырезал просто кусок что бы понятно было что и откуда нужно получитью Полная там 1000 строк. Полей Item может быть многою Но суть в том, что вынимать нужно из поля <routes>
    <item>

Comment: Попробуйте сайт вроде такого: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

Comment: Он почему то видит не все поля в большом вложении

Comment: Основная проблема в том, что я не могу понять и найти пример для ознакомления что бы увидеть как доставать элементы из "глубоких вложений"